# MySQL reporting unknow column on a column that was not specified

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm trying to insert values in to a table but I'm hitting an error that I cannot overcome -

```
INSERT INTO dd_poll_options (option_text, option_order, poll_id) VALUES (a, 0, 6),(b, 1, 6),(c, 2, 6),(d, 3, 6),(e, 4, 6),(f, 5, 6);
```

The error being generated as below. As you can see from the code sample, `'a'` is a value, not a column name -

> Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'

I've checked the [MySQL 'INSERT' doc's](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) which seem to suggest the code is sound, with the give example -

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

I've tried wrapping the column names in backtricks (`), but the same error is generaged.

Can someone please help me find why this error is occuring, and how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around strings like `a`

```
INSERT INTO dd_poll_options (option_text, option_order, poll_id) 
VALUES ('a', 0, 6),
       ('b', 1, 6),
       ('c', 2, 6),
       ('d', 3, 6),
       ('e', 4, 6),
       ('f', 5, 6);
```

Otherwise the DB engine would look for a column with that name.

Comment: Thank you. I was under the impression MySQL would action it as a string, as that is what the column `option_text` is defined as (TEXT).